# How do you delete CloudKit "Field Names" programatically?

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I've been looking around everywhere but all I can find is deleting a Zone though the Field Names stay.  The only other way I found was you have to log into the CloudKit dashboard and do it manually. Is this the only way?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the Dashboard to make any changes to your schema. It is not possible to modify the schema programatically.

Making schema changes is something you only need to do during development, and the schema is created on demand, so there's no need for client side API to manage the schema.

You don't need to send every possible field when updating a record, so you can just stop using the field you want to delete and clean it up later in the dashboard.